# Access to PHP $_GET and $_POST in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In a wordpress page I have a form where, after the pressure of submit botton, the same page is reloaded and it sends an email with the information in the form. The problem is that, as soon as I try to save the page, if in the php code there is a $_GET[],$_POST[] or $_REQUEST[] array, wordpress does not let me to save the changes, and the last code I wrote (those with $_variables) disappears. If I make an external php script and I call it in the wordpress page, I get "Internal Server Error" when I connect to the page.

I tried with two different php wp plugins, and I have the same problem in both.

Does anyone know why?

EDIT:
Here is an example of code I tried, it is the simpest example I found and it is still not working:

```
<?php
function test() {
  echo $_POST["user"]; 
}    

if (isset($_POST[])){ //If it is the first time, it does nothing   
  test();
}
?>
```

Here is the form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="enter a text" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="test()" />
</form>
```

Anyway it is as if the wordpress parser recognizes the variables and refuses to save, if I wrote, for instance, only the following code `

```
<?php
$_GET[];
?>
```

it give me the same problem, but writing

```
<?php
$_HELLO[];
?>
```

though it returns error when I call the page in the browser (obviously considering that $_HELL does not exist), it let me save.

EDIT 2: Very strange, if I print all the post array with

```
`<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>`
```

it works, and it prints   "array(1) { ["user"]=> string(3) "123" }",
BUT IF I TRY TO ACCESS TO THE ELEMENT WITH THE KEY "USER" USING [] IT GIVES ME ERROR!

Comment: can you post your code piece? i used $_POST and $_GET values to get my data in wordpress too, but i doesnt have any problem with that...

Comment: You are right, I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

$_POST and $_GET are also work in wordpress too..

Remove the square bracket[ ] on $_POST, it will work.

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="enter a text" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="test()" />
</form>

<?php
function test() {
 echo $_POST["user"]; 
}    

if (isset($_POST)){ //If it is the first time, it does nothing   
  test();
}
?>
```

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: No, it does not work cause to the brackets in "echo $_POST["user"];"

Comment: Remove bracket within if condition only, not that echo part. Did you get any error??

Comment: Yes, it does not save the changes, like before

Comment: Do you want to store your text in database?

Comment: Regarding the errors, if I write the code in the wp page it simply does not save the changes, and if I load an external php script it gives me "Internal Server Error"

Comment: I need to send those data by email

Comment: Could it be that I have to set some security setting about the POST method in wordpress?

Comment: I think its a server issue and check you have permissions to access the page or not.. If not, first give permission for that page, then try to reload.

Comment: Yes, I seen your edit part.. Surely echo $_POST["user"]; will work. First you try without using function.